# Can't play on minecraft mineplex together

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My brother and I can't play on mineplex together,  we can never see each other or play on the same survival game as we somehow on different servers even if we try?

Comment: A mineplex tag is unneccessary.  Until and unless we get rather more than a single question about it.

Comment: How are you an awesome mineplex gamer if you can't play it?

Comment: @ChaseC He can't play it *with his brother*. Anyway, do you chase many seas?

Comment: @coiax Oooohhhhh. And no, not particularly hehe :)

Answer (score 8):

Mineplex is split into a number of separate servers, both in lobby and in games.

By using the Lobby Selector (clock) you can select the lobby server that your avatar will appear in.

By right clicking on the entity in front of the game type you want to play (whether Nether Skeleton for Mixed Arcade, or Iron Golem for Super Smash Mobs), you can see a list of available servers (where yellow is in-game, and green is undergoing sign ups/pre game).

Communicate with your brother which server you're joining, and both join the same one, and you should be together.

Comment: If you're still not seeing each other even if you're on the same game servers, then that might be a case of CANTFIX, unless you can contact a Mineplex admin and ask for assistance.

Comment: After reading your answer, it seems like you are more on the right track with me, although sometimes when I play with my friends, I can do what I describe in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since Mineplex is such an enourmous server, it has to has multiple different lobbies at a time, which means when you click into the server, it puts you into a random lobby, with different survival games servers, bridges servers, etc., for that said lobby.If you want to play with your brother, when you join Mineplex, ask your brother to select a lobby, for example, the bottom left one in the available lobbies. This should make it so you and your brother are on the same server. Then if you want to play on the same survival games server, just remember to select the same server as him. Hope this helps!

Comment: Would you happen to know how Mineplex accomplishes multiple servers? Is it a Bukkit plugin that links them together? Do they even use Bukkit?

Comment: @Santa_Claus Not sure, I could look it up though.

Comment: Yeah, I've always wondered how they do it, but I haven't been able to find anywhere its been revealed.

Comment: @SantaClaus my question looked at this https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168136/do-large-minecraft-servers-run-on-multiple-different-machines

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the clock in your hotbar, and join the same lobby. Then you can do /party then type in your brother's username. Follow the instructions, and then once the "party leader" joins a game, the whole party will join.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what the other answers state, you also need to be logging into the same IP address -- when you add the server, edit the Server Address so both say either "us.mineplex.com" or "eu.mineplex.com".