# Playing Mineplex from one IP address with two different accounts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

We are trying to play on Mineplex from one public IP addres under 2 different Minecraft accounts from two different PCs behing home router.
Still after many tries, [sugestions form this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168675/cant-play-on-minecraft-mineplex-together), selecting the same lobby etc., cannot see each other.

When as a `Player1` I try the `/PARTY Player2` command, it says

> You cannot party with yourself

Still it is showing at the top screen `Welcome Player1 to the Mineplex network`. The other PC has correctly `Welcome Player2 to the Mineplex network`. We choose the same lobby (e.g. 15), still in minigames we see completely different numbers of servers.

Should I login anew or something like that, or the single public IP is the problem?

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking about partying or minigames?

Comment: I see, I thought it is connected, just we wanted to play together and no way, though everyrhing seemed setup ok

Comment: We want both party and play minigames together, the non-functional PARTY command could be a clue as per what is wrong, on both computers has Mineplex been played as Player1 before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your IP is a problem. However, you could try using a VPN service like TunnelBear or Betternet to get another IP adress. Really weird that this is happening to you, I can play Minecraft with others in the same house just fine. Are you absolutely sure you are not typing `/party invite [your own name]`? Also, make sure you are both using `eu.mineplex.com` or `us.mineplex.com` If really nothing works try reinstalling Minecraft.